# Not all list items floating correctly

Tags: html, css, sass

I am working on a gallery grid (first block of 6 images) and I cannot for the life of me seeing why not all list items are displaying properly. It mostly displays correctly, however, if you downscale the browser, at about 700px, the items start flicking and not displaying as they should.

I usually use a right padding of 10px for my gallery items, as this didn't work on this occasion I have tried a right border of 10px but still the problem persists.

Can anyone see what the problem is? Live url is [here.](http://staging.whitstabledesign.com/KCP/)

Code is:

```
.feature {

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0 -10px 30px 0;
        padding: 0 !important;

        li {
            border-right: 10px solid #ffffff;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            width: 33.33%;

            img {
                width: 100%;
            }

            .inner {
                position: absolute;
                padding: 20px;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the (original) width/height ratio of your images: They are all 500x333px, but the third one is 600x400, which makes its automatic height slightly bigger than it is in all other instances. And therefore the 5th `li` element doesn't float under the third one (when only two fit in a row), but next to it, because the third is about 1px higher than the fourth one.

The easiest solution would be to change the original size of the fourth image to 500x333

Comment: You are completely right! Thanks for seeing this - turns out the thumbnail resize didn't do it's job initially. Thanks for your help.